# Windows Linux shared file system ownership

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, filesystems, network-share

We have a network file system shared among Linux and Windows servers.

Whatever Windows writes gives ownership to root when observed from Linux.

In Linux we have a tomcat user which thus, is not able to write in the directories created by Windows.

We are not able to set POSIX ACLs using setfacl since it is a network file system. It says Operation not supported.

We tried to set ownership from Windows for the newly created directories, but the tomcat user principal is not found.

We are using java programs on both sides.

Please suggest.

Comment: By what protocol are you sharing the filesystem? How did you configure it on the Linux client?

Comment: It a NAS volume, mounted on Linux using fstab and on Windows using NFS.

Comment: It's also shared to Linux via NFS?

Comment: @MichaelHampton 172.30.0.3:/edmsdmz This is how it is showing in df command so I guess NFS only.